# Given $X$ and $Y$ and a percent, how do I calculate the quantity that is that percent between them?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is a really dumb question, but I cannot find answers on Google for some reason or other.  All the answers seem to be buried under mounds of percent difference formulas (which is not what I am asking).

I am trying to generate a value between two variables based on a percentage.

$$\begin{align*}
0\% &= X \qquad \text{(the minimum value)}\\\\
50\% &= \frac{X + Y}{2}\\\\
100\% &= Y\qquad \text{(the maximum value)}
\end{align*}$$

What would the formula be?

Comment: Readers, it might be useful to know that this is essentially the _lerp()_ function, which stands for linear interpolation.  I figured this out after a little under a month that I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$X+(\text{percent here})\cdot(Y-X)$$
So for example,

$X+(25\%)\cdot(Y-X)$ is $25$ percent of the way to $Y$, from $X$.

Answer (score 2):

The formula for "$t$ percent", where $t$ is any number between $0$ and $100$, is
$$\left(1-\frac{t}{100}\right)X+\left(\frac{t}{100}\right)Y$$